# Nette Framework - Route a signal

Tags: php, nette

I'm using the [kdyby/facebook](https://github.com/Kdyby/Google) extension for Facebook authentication, which uses a link to `open` signal in `fbLogin` component.

```
<a n:href="fbLogin-open!">Login using facebook</a>
```

This results into **/?do=fbLogin-open!** How could route this link to **/login/facebook**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your router (commonly in */app/RouterFactory.php*) make a new route.

```
$router[] = new Route('login/<do>', [
  'presenter' => 'Login',
  'action' => 'fbLogin',
  'do' => array(
    Route::FILTER_TABLE => array(
      'facebook' => 'fbLogin-open'
    )
  )
]);
```

Now you can use */login/facebook* route.